# does :hover work for image element in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm just trying to change the cursor to pointer when the cursor is hovered through image but it's not working.

Does img:hover works in chrome 13 or other browsers.

```
img:hover
{
cusror:pointer;
}
```

and html is sa below

```
<div>

<img src="images/ocean1.jpg" width="200" height="120">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `cursor: pointer` you don't need to use `hover`. Just use:

```
img {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The cursor will then automatically change to a pointer when you hover over any image.

Comment: Oops it's my mistake. I used cusror instead of cursor. Anyways both img and img:hover were working..Thanks a lot

Comment: @Sukumar if this fixed your problem, please click the green check. We both get rep points. Glad that it helped!

Comment: @JJ yeh..just 6 more minutes to go :)

Comment: For any `cursor` for that matter.